# resizing browser moves my button around

Tags: css, html

I have a background image, I am trying to put the button at the middle bottom somewhere. But when I move the browser to the left or side of the screen, the button moves around slightly. But I want it to stay exactly where it was before. Can somebody tell me what I am doing wrong?
Here is my CSS at below.

```
body
{
    margin:0;
    padding :0;
    background:url(ht.JPG);
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-size:cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    font-family:sans-serif;
}

#loginbutton 
{
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size:18px;
    opacity:0.6;
    align-items: center;
    text-align:center;
    border:none;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background:transparent;
    color:black;
    background-color:#EAEAEA;



    position: absolute;
    top:69%;
    left:45%;


}
```

Below is my button at the html.

```
<a href="register.html" ><button type="submit" value="Submit" id="loginbutton">Login</button></a>
```

Comment: But when I move the browser to the left or side of the screen, the button moves around slightly. Do you mean resizing ?

Comment: @VishnuKyatannawar yes when I resize the  browser that happens. correct.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/n09sos3c/1/ >> Is it okay if you try making the background image fixed but still on browser resize the button will move slightly, since the button will not shrink like the background on resize.

Comment: @VishnuKyatannawar your code fixed my problem. Thank you ! Quick question though, there are two centers after no-repeat, what does each do?

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/background/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried fitting the background image to window height:

```
     [https://jsfiddle.net/n09sos3c/3/][1]
```

Note that this will not ensure on very small window resolutions the button will still not fit at the right place, since the image will shrink but button won't.

You can learn about background shorthand here: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/background/